# Third-party-app for merging Django user objects?

Tags: django, merge, foreign-key-relationship

I need to merge two users in a Django database.
So I wonder if there is any simple way (maybe a dedicated app) to do that?

**For example:**

We have `user_a` and `user_b` and some models that have foreign keys to the `User` model (`Books`, `Interests`, `Teams` and so on…).

By merging users, I want to delete the object `user_b` and to set all foreign keys pointing to this object to point to `user_a`. And – this is my main concern – I want the objects that need to be changed because they reference the to-be-deleted object to be determined automatically without having to specify a list of those Models and foreign key fields in them manually.

Is this already implemented and I'm reinventing the wheel?

**Is this possible?**

If not, please show me the way to do it: how can I build a list of Django models that have a foreign key to a specific model (`User` in my case) in runtime?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I found this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2283/ . I'm going to have to modify it though, to make it recursive. I will share my code once I'm done.

Comment: https://media.tenor.com/_esBJqVotiwAAAAM/still-waiting-where-are-you.gif

Answer (score 2):

With Django 1.8 and beyond, you could achieve this robustly using the [Model _meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/).

Specifically, you could use [`Options.get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model). This will even let you handle generic relations.

You'll need to consider for each related field whether you want to add or replace on merge. This decision depends on your application logic and corresponding schema choices.

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=123)
related_fields = [
    f for f in u._meta.get_fields()
    if (f.one_to_many or f.one_to_one)
    and not f.concrete
]
for f in related_fields:
    # use field's attributes to perform an update
```